# Is it reasonable to use a GPG certificate for more than one email-account?

Tags: security, gnupg

Are there any known issues or is this way just a time-saver for lazy people.

Comment: You mean same certificate?

Comment: Yes, same certificate associated with serveral email-adresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking in terms of logical sense then I can only say that I don't see why it would not be reasonable as it identifies the person and a person may own more than one email address.